# Countif in DAX PowerPivot

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I need to calculate the average weekly quantity of a month in Power Pivot, so I need to count how many weeks in the column of "Wkly #" on the 1st table "Fcst Volume" from the 2nd table "Period". For example, I need it to be 5 for the 1st "Wkly #" as there are 5 "P03" on the 2nd table and I need it to be 4 for the 2nd "Wkly #" as there are 4 "P04" on the 2nd table.
Can someone please tell me how to do Countif in DAX? Many thanks

[image: Fcst Volume]

[image: Period]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new column in Table1:

`=CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Table2'),FILTER(Table2,'Table2'[Period]='Table1'[Period]))`

Answer (score 0):

When you do countif/sumif, it is an aggregation by partition. The direct dax equivalent is `ALLEXCEPT`

If you have table like following
[image: Solution]

You can write the calculated column like following

```
=CALCULATE(COUNT(Table1[Column1]),ALLEXCEPT(Table1,Table1[Column1]))
```